# C# : Creating a SecureString reading from an Encrypted file

Tags: c#, encryption, securestring

I'm a QA Automation Analyst and in one of my tests I need to validate that a triggered email was sent to the customer's email. Using exchange service I am able to connect to the mailbox created for test and validate that there is an unread email there and do whatever I need with the info.

The issue arises because since I need to log into Exchange Server, the service account credentials are required and I don't want to expose the password. The solution I tried to come up with was to have an encrypted file with the password and make my code decrypt the file and create a `SecureString` with it and then encrypt again... the problem is, while debugging the code, the password would still be exposed.

Below the code template::

```
private static SecureString getServiceAccountPassword()
{
        string folderPath = DataEnum.SA_PASSWORD_FILE;
        Encryption.Decrypt(folderPath);
        SecureString pasw = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in File.OpenText(folderPath).ReadToEnd().ToCharArray())
        {
            pasw.AppendChar(c);
        }

        Encryption.Encrypt(folderPath);
        return pasw;
}
```

So my question: is there a way to create a `SecureString` differently, without exposing the password? Or am I using the wrong approach? Any input will be helpful...

Best regards.

Comment: I am curious to see the answers to this from people who are a bit more in the know, but just to throw in in my knowledge. The purpose of SecureStrings I think is that the data is encrypted in memory, so if some was so take a memory dump of the system in question while the password was in memory they wouldn't be able to get the password. I don't think secure string will do what you want them too. IMO what is the need to have the password encrypted in the debugger? If it the account it is for is that sensitive it shouldnt be used in tests, you should set up a separate test account

Comment: The idea is to assert accountability while using a service account that has interactive logon, only one person should know the password. But we still need an account to log into to exchange server and validate that email. I thought about using the employees own password (the one that is executing the test) but we aim to schedule all tests to be executed on a VM and in this case we cannot use one employee's credentials.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right and the best approach would be to separete the responsabilities and create a shared user without interactive logon that would just be used to check the mailbox...

Comment: My thinking on this was that if I wanted to see that password and I was another tester, I could for example create a new test that decrpyts the password file and just saves it out as a new file or just pulls the password into a normal string. If you are going to expose the password like that, make sure it's a password to an account that literally has no access and no rights. If that's not possible then to me that means you need to redesign the test. As I think you're always going to be vulnerably to exposing the password to people you don't want to expose it to

Comment: I see your point... I was thinking that another tester would not be able to do that since he would not know the key for decrypting the file, but I exposed the methods to encrypt and decrypt the file. You got a point... Using different accounts seems to be the best approach indeed...

Comment: Besides all valid points said above - you are also using SecureString incorrectly (not that you should use it at all here, but still), because `File.OpenText(folderPath).ReadToEnd()` creates regular `string` with your password and the whole point of SecureString is to avoid that.

Comment: If the test can access the mailbox, then anyone with privileges to debug the code can access the mailbox as well, because they have the right to inspect and modify any code, including the code that runs right after any data is decrypted. There is a reason that, by default, you only have the right to debug processes you own, and debugging processes you do not own requires administrative privileges. The art of hiding things a program needs from the user that's running it is the cornerstone of DRM. It can succeed at discouraging and delaying people, but it can't securely keep them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my checklist:

- Don't use an encrypted file.  If you MUST use an encrypted file, encrypt it with the Windows Data Protection API.
- Use Group Managed Service Account and Win32 API call GetServiceAccountPassword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecMgmt/getserviceaccountpassword